# Dragging HTML element , implemented with HammerJS , is jittery on touch device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hammer.js

I have a list of HTML elements as cards stacked on top of each other. I am trying to drag the element with `pan` event using `HammerJS`

```
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChildren('slides') slides;
  @ViewChild('stack') stack;
  constructor(    
    this.cards = [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    let hammer = new Hammer.Manager(this.stack.nativeElement, {  preventDefault: true,
      recognizers: [      [ Hammer.Pan, { threshold: 2 }] ]
    });
    hammer.get('pan').set({ direction: window['Hammer'].DIRECTION_ALL });
    this.element = this.slides.first.nativeElement;
    hammer.on('panmove', (ev) => {
      this.handlePan(ev);
    });
  }
  handlePan(
    let deltaX = ev.deltaX;
    let deltaY = ev.deltaY;
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.element, 'transform',`translate(${deltaX}px,${deltaY}px)`);
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-content  >
  <div #stack class="stack">
  <ion-card *ngFor = "let c of cards" #slides >
    <ion-card-content>
      c
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

home.scss

```
  ion-card{
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
  }
```

This works smoothly in browser but on touch devices its jittery. But if I remove  `position: absolute` from css it works smoothly on touch devices as well but the cards are not stacked on top of each other. I just feel the`panmove` event is triggered little late on touch devices for some reason.I am stuck on this problem for some days, any kind of help in figuring out the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: This may be a known bug, at the bottom of this page they offer a work around without hammerjs https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/250

Comment: @numbtongue I did try the solution but its still jittery. I am unsure what difference position absolute makes in touch action

Comment: Position absolute is kind of extreme way of styling things.. You should be able to make it work with relative positioning and floating elements or using z-index..

Comment: Not a css expert but everywhere I look stacking is done though absolute position

Comment: What if you use position:fixed..

Comment: this.renderer.setStyle(elem,"transform",`translate3d(0, 0, 0) translate(${xtranslate}px,${ytranslate}px)`) surprisingly this solved the issue. Had to add translate3d as well not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer. The issue is that styling is pretty slow on mobile devices. So have to make GPU acceleration in mobile devices. Simply add `translate3d(0,0,0)` which will pull in GPU acceleration.

```
this.renderer.setStyle(elem,"transform",`translate3d(0, 0, 0) translate(${xtranslate}px,${ytranslate}px)`)
```